# Запятые при использовании метода map() в hint'е Яндекс карты (react-yandex-maps)

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Я создаю кастомный хинт при ховере метки, код выглядит примерно так:

```
properties={{ hintContent: `<div class="flex">
   ${states.map((state: string) => {
      if (state == 'vacant')
       return '<div class="w-3 h-3 rounded mr-1 bg-green"> </div>'
      if (state == 'occupied')
       return '<div class="w-3 h-3 rounded mr-1 bg-red"> </div>'
       return '<div class="w-3 h-3 rounded mr-1 bg-gray-brown"> </div>'
         })}
</div>`}}
```

Всё работает нормально, однако при рендере хинта, после каждого элемента мэпа появляется запята. Через девтулзы в элементах дом дерева она отображается просто как " , ". Не совсем понимаю, чем это вызвано и как с этим бороться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ps. Предоставил код только который рендерит зеленые кружки

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-yandex-maps-issue-101-forked-v3ql46?file=/src/index.js

Воссоздал появление запятых, по ховеру на плейсмарк видно

Comment: А можете минимально рабочий пример собрать? Хотя бы на https://jsbin.com По маленькому кусочку кода, не отражающему общей картины едва ли кто скажет, что у вас за запятые и как от них избавиться.

Comment: @YaCor' Добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогли в issues либы.
Из за того, что рендерится мэп как отдельные строки выставляются запятые, при помощи join(), можно объединить в одну строку и избавиться от запятых
В случае примера: `hintContent: arr.join('')`